# Error when installing rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

i just install ruby on windows system

```
C:\Users\PC>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
```

but when i try to install rails

```
C:\Users\PC>gem install rails --include-dependencies
INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError)
    code converter not found (UTF-16LE to IBM737)
```

could you please help me...

i have english version of windows 7 Ultimate with greek language installed

Comment: Windows is not an ideal dev environment for rails, the community mostly uses OSX and ubuntu, so it's likely that a lot of scripts and gems won't work unmodified on non-*nix environments.

Comment: @Charles: True, but expecting Ruby, RubyGems and Rails to work on Windows is not unreasonable.

Comment: Yeah, it was more of a word of warning than anything related to the question. I've been burned myself when I first tried to setup a rails dev environment on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Command Prompt code page:

`chcp 850`

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) for windows if you can use Ruby 1.8.7. It will install ruby and rails and other dependencies for you. There are screencasts and other help as well.

If you need ruby 1.9.2+, then it looks like you might be out of luck unless you upgrade to ruby 1.9.3. You can read about it [here](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4738).

Good luck!